# Calculating maximum word frequency in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm stuck with last bits of my assignment. I tried several times, but my code doesn't pass the test. Could somebody revise and point out what I did wrong please?

```
# Implement the calculate_line_with_highest_frequency() method to:
#* calculate the maximum value for highest_wf_count contained by the LineAnalyzer objects in analyzers array
#  and stores this result in the highest_count_across_lines attribute.
#* identifies the LineAnalyzer objects in the analyzers array that have highest_wf_count equal to highest_count_across_lines 
#  attribute value determined previously and stores them in highest_count_words_across_lines.

def calculate_line_with_highest_frequency
  highest_count_across_lines = Hash.new(0)

    @analyzers.each do |line|
      line.content.split.each do |word|
      highest_wf_count[word.downcase] +=1
    end
  end

  @highest_count_across_lines = highest_wf_count.values.max

  @highest_count_words_across_lines = Array.new
  @analyzers.each do |line|
    line.highest_count_across_lines.each do |word|
      @highest_count_words_across_lines << line if highest_count_across_lines[word] == @highest_wf_count
    end
  end
```

Comment: Knowing what test you're trying to pass would help.

Comment: If this is an assignment, it may be best to ask your professor or a tutor. The code you've provided does not provide enough insight into the assignment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]". We need more information: What is your minimal input data, and what output do you need? If the code doesn't work you need to explain what you intend for the code to do to meet the requirements and what you see that it's not doing. Please don't expect us to replace your instructor; They know much better what you are supposed to learn based on what you've been taught to this point. We can't just jump in.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should write initialize method in Solution class:

```
def initialize ()
    @analyzers=Array.new   
end
```

So your analyzers are initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I am also do this assignment for coursera. I pass all tests except the last one.Is you pass test or still doing?
I think we help each other in this.
Send me your email address please

I couldn't pass this last test

```
Solution#calculate_line_with_highest_frequency calculates highest count words across lines to be will, it, really
 Failure/Error: words_found solution.highest_count_words_across_lines.map(&:highest_wf_words).flatten
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `highest_wf_words' for "really":String
 # ./spec/solution_spec.rb:38:in `map'
 # ./spec/solution_spec.rb:38:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the task carefully you'll notice that `highest_count_words_across_lines` variable should contain LineAnalyzer objects of the lines that has highest count words. Not the words.